# Sampling distribution of sample means - some basic questions that I have not found an answer to.

Tags: statistics

Okay, Assume each sample has mean $x$ and standard deviation $y$ then the mean of the sample means would be $x$ and standard deviation of the sample means would be $\frac{y}{n}$ what is n here? Is it the number of samples we have, or is it the number of elements of the samples we have? I'm confused.

And also if I have a population with normal distribution I with say mean $x$ and deviation $y$ I immediately conclude that samples which are identically and independently distributed have the same mean and deviation, how come? And I just realized this is not the case for normal populations only, it is also the case for whatever distribution the population has.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n,$ having $n$ observations,
randomly sampled from a population with mean $\mu,$ variance $\sigma^2,$
and standard deviation $\sigma.$

*Random sampling* means that the
expectation (or mean) of each observation $X_i$ is $E(X_i) = \mu,$
that the variance of each observation is $Var(X_i) = \sigma^2,$
that the SD of each observation is $SD(X_i) = \sigma,$ and that
the random variables $X_i$ are independent of each other.

Then, one can prove, that the sample mean $\bar X = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,$ has $E(\bar X) = \mu.$ (We say that the sample mean
$\bar X$ is an unbiased estimator of the population $\mu.$)
Also, $Var(\bar X) = \sigma^2/n$ 
and $SD(\bar X) = \sqrt{Var(\bar X)} = \sigma/\sqrt{n}.$

Moreover, the sample variance 
$S_X^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar X)^2$ has $E(S_X^2) = \sigma^2.$

Please be sure to distinguish between observations within a sample and samples,
between population means and sample means, and between population variances
and sample variances.

Also, it is not a good idea to use symbols such as $x$ and $y$ for means and variances; I assume you did that to avoid problems printing
$\mu$ and $\sigma^2$; that can be done by typing `$\mu$` and `$\sigma^2$`, respectively.